# How to add multiple members to a group by chef

Tags: chef-infra

How can I add multiple members to a group by chef?

I tried like this, but it fails.

```
group "git" do
  action :modify
  members "foo, bar"
  append true
end
```

I can do like this, but `members` seems to accept multiple users. How can I use it?

```
%w(foo bar).each do |m|
  group "git" do
    action :modify
    members m
    append true
  end
end
```

Comment: What error do you get on the comma separated approach? Have you tried an array syntax?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, `members ["foo", "bar"]` works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most arguments that accept multiple inputs in Chef work with standard ruby array syntax. I can't find an example just now, and it's very frustrating that the [`group` docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_group.html#attributes) don't provide an example of multiple users. In fact, they just say

> `members`    Indicates which users should be set or appended to a group.

And only provide examples with single users. That said, `members ["foo", "bar"]` should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a standard Group block with multiple members:

```
group "rbenv" do
  action :manage
  members ['member1','member2','member3']
end
```

You could also use a loop from a whitespace array:

```
%w{ erin john nick jenna kris }.each do |memberlist|
  group "rbenv" do
    action :manage
    members memberlist
  end
end
```

With this whitespace array option, you're now set to either continue with that type of array, or get an array from Chef data bags or even a MySQL database. In my case, Chef connects to MySQL to get info about users, and provisions them accordingly.